# How to change the filename before saving in carrierwave in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

In the controller I have:

```
ext = File.extname(params[:file].original_filename)
 basename = File.basename(params[:file].original_filename, ext)
 time = Time.now.to_i

 for_hash = Digest::MD5.hexdigest([basename, time].join(''))[0..5]
 new_file_name = [for_hash, ext].join('')
```

And it save to database the new file name. But how can with this code art change the file name in the folder before the save?

Comment: This is very good described in [Create random and unique filenames for all versioned files](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to:-Create-random-and-unique-filenames-for-all-versioned-files)

Answer (score 2):

In your uploader file, you can change the filename,

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
   def filename
     "#{model.id}.jpg" # to name file with their id
   end
 ....
end
```

I did it a long time ago, I think that was this.